# Can't push Rails test app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Here is my heroku log. I've tried a lot of different things and nothing seems to be working. Thanks in advance. I'm trying to learn rails right now so this would be a big help

```
Your version of git is 1.9.3. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here:          https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
    2015-01-15T06:30:15.421207+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    2015-01-15T06:30:15.421200+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    2015-01-15T06:30:15.421194+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
    2015-01-15T06:30:15.421196+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:30:15.421188+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-01-15T06:30:38.686555+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup` by calvin.hemington@gmail.com
    2015-01-15T06:30:42.966719+00:00 heroku[run.9585]: Awaiting client
    2015-01-15T06:30:43.003428+00:00 heroku[run.9585]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup`
    2015-01-15T06:30:43.289912+00:00 heroku[run.9585]: State changed from starting to up
    2015-01-15T06:30:47.395869+00:00 heroku[run.9585]: Process exited with status 1
    2015-01-15T06:30:47.421918+00:00 heroku[run.9585]: State changed from up to complete
    2015-01-15T06:31:08.489744+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by calvin.hemington@gmail.com
    2015-01-15T06:31:13.231603+00:00 heroku[run.1664]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
    2015-01-15T06:31:13.180138+00:00 heroku[run.1664]: Awaiting client
    2015-01-15T06:31:13.637883+00:00 heroku[run.1664]: State changed from starting to up
    2015-01-15T06:31:21.004530+00:00 heroku[run.1664]: Process exited with status 0
    2015-01-15T06:31:21.017929+00:00 heroku[run.1664]: State changed from up to complete
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.943880+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=floating-crag-5806.herokuapp.com request_id=104dce4d-2118-4577-a884-0dc27f141473 fwd="67.164.99.238" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=1829
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.932582+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 67.164.99.238 at 2015-01-15 06:31:59 +0000
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937810+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937829+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937818+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937832+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937825+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937836+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937816+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937820+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937831+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937808+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937806+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937823+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937833+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937811+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937838+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937839+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937799+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937804+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937840+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937821+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937828+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937802+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937826+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937835+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937813+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    2015-01-15T06:31:59.937815+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.225976+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 67.164.99.238 at 2015-01-15 06:32:02 +0000
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232207+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232248+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232271+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232198+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232232+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232249+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232209+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232255+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232233+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232250+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232205+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232235+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232258+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232236+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232242+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232253+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232230+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232238+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232239+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232241+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232252+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232245+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232268+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232269+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232246+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.232256+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    2015-01-15T06:32:02.250087+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=floating-crag-5806.herokuapp.com request_id=96d844c8-7751-434d-8712-99ce31f08667 fwd="67.164.99.238" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=26ms status=404 bytes=1829
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.428693+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=floating-crag-5806.herokuapp.com request_id=983baae6-d5e7-4d17-9225-4244eb90b653 fwd="67.164.99.238" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=1829
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.424957+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 67.164.99.238 at 2015-01-15 06:37:37 +0000
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426886+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426893+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426895+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426898+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426902+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426905+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426907+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426909+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426913+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426915+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426920+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426918+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426890+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426926+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426900+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426928+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426931+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426939+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426911+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426922+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426937+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426932+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426934+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426943+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-01-15T06:37:37.426941+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Comment: Does everything work fine in your local app when you go to the root page?

Answer (score 0):

the error message is:
`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/")`

In `routes.rb` please make sure you point the root path somewhere like:
`root :to => 'index#index'`

don't forget to restart the rails server after changing the routes file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a routing error `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/")` (from your `heroku logs`).
Which means that you tried to access a page in your Heroku app that doesn't have a **GET** action in any of your controllers that is tied the root (`"/"`).

To fix this, you either don't go to the root page, or (in *config/routes.rb*)

```
root 'pages#main'
```

to the controller `pages` and action `main` which you'd like to handle your page.

(from [Ruby On Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root))